# Travel insurance for second leg of flight on account of missing the first leg of the flight

Tags: insurance

My friend is traveling from Guwahati in India to Mumbai in India and thence to Paris. The current situation in Guwahati is a bit volatile in that there is a curfew. I was wondering if there are any travel insurance that will insure the  already bought international ticket in the case of missing the first leg due to curfew or riots.

Comment: Possibly unlikely if “known peril” (something that a traveler would reasonably know about before buying a policy) applies, as it would seem to do in this case. What travel insurance does the passenger already have?

Comment: The traveller didn't have any at the point. The discussion is moot now but I am answering to respond in case you have some comment for other people reading this.